# What is the solution for exited with code=3221226356?

Tags: c, error-handling, realloc

I'm trying to delete the values which are divisible by 5 and shorten the size of the array when deleting an item. but I'm getting the error exited with code=3221226356. How can i solve this?

This is my Code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void delete(int arr[],int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i]%5==0){
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                arr[i]=arr[j];
            }
            n--;
            arr=(int *)realloc(arr,sizeof(int)*n);
        }
    }
    
}
int main(){
    int arr[]={7,16,20,28,35,45,49,65};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    delete(arr,n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The pointer `arr` in `delete` points to a statically-allocated array; you can't free/realloc it. Use malloc if you want to later realloc.

Comment: (You have a second bug, where change `arr` in `delete`, but not `arr` in `main`.)